# "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved."

Tags: support, locked-posts, specific-answer

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1212596) to "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags" (a.k.a. "Tony the Pony") has this message:

[image]

The "visit meta" link is for http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

1. What are the disputes about its content?
2. How are these disputes "being resolved"?
3. What additional info does meta.stackoverflow.com have?

---

(I await #3 to be solved by [self-fulfilling prophecy](https://xkcd.com/446/) in this thread.)

Comment: The revision history should provide some insight. I'd say there is no real ongoing dispute, but enough is enough.

Comment: @Bart, so you are saying that "conflicts about its content are being resolved" is incorrect? It should be "there are conflicts about its content"?

Comment: It is an automated message, there doesn't *have* to be a Meta post about it. The link is certainly correct, and MSO is the right place to point to now.

Comment: Or "stop messing with this answer, it's here to stay as is" @paul ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, there doesn't have to be a post. (Could be...doesn't have to be.) But if you are going to tell someone to go somewhere for some more information, you might want to actually point them to where there is more information.

Comment: With the MSO-MSE split I am reading every post as a bug report for link targets; I wasn't addressing the fact that the post in question is an exceptional situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Is there a meta post/record regarding the disputes about the content of the classic regex-for-xhtml answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/is-there-a-meta-post-record-regarding-the-disputes-about-the-content-of-the-clas)... hey wait a minute, I can't do that anymore

Comment: and another "possibile duplicate": [Why does the RegEx answer keep getting locked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134933/why-does-the-regex-answer-keep-getting-locked)

Comment: Even today, people flag this answer regularly, requesting that it be deleted. There have been 88 flags on that answer and counting, and 110 deleted comments. If it wasn't locked, it would be regularly defaced just due to its popularity. I wish that anyone who had flagged that post as "worthless spam" or "vandalism" would be banned from flagging for a month.

Comment: @BradLarson, excellent idea. Just as reviewers have reject the occasional SO-introduced "traps" or else have reviewing rights temporarily suspended, those who flag this post would receive similar treatment :)

Comment: @BradLarson The problem is that the posting is not an answer, it is a joke, and linking to it is insulting and informative and wrong. It is a rude thing that puts people off, and we should not encourage rudeness.  As a bare minimum, no one should be allowed to link to it, including in dup-votes, which are even worse. Optimally, salt should be sown in the fields of Zalgo, and it should trouble us now.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: @tchrist Agreed. "How can I parse this small set of simple things", "You can't parse this huge set of complicated things". Wut?

Comment: What is meant by ***"Zalgo delenda est"*** which I see a few places here?

Comment: Well, it doesn't entirely explain that phrase, but I did find this, which explains the "Zalgo" reference: "[Zalgo is often associated with scrambled text on webpages](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo)".

Comment: @bjb568, HTML is not a small set of simple things. As I understand it, he was parsing HTML.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was a fertile ground for edit wars between users who wanted to remove the Zalgo text and those who wanted to leave it in there.

The common way to prevent such war is locking the post, and that's what the team chose to do.

I doubt it will be unlocked in the future, as the core "problem" is the post itself. So this is an exception to "contents are  being resolved".

> What additional info does meta.stackoverflow.com have

This meta site is for reporting bugs in Stack Overflow, asking new feature requests, starting discussions and asking support questions. You did the last, asking for support about a specific locked answer.

Also, as with any locked post if you think it should be edited, flag it for moderator attention, choose "Other" and explain what should be edited. Any diamond mod can edit, if they agree with this.

Comment: @Tim do you mean a single moderator won't usually act upon such a flag by himself/herself? (but rather ask for advice from other mods)

Comment: Not necessarily - I think he's using "they" here as a [gender-neutral pronoun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222024/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral). Of course, you could change this to "he/she agrees" if you prefer :)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/145/

Comment: @BoltClock Because the problem is the unmentionable post itself, then the solution is clear: consign it to oblivion.  It may be locked, but people keep linking to it or using it for close-voting, and this is a serious problem.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: Given all of these comments it seems that a message that says "permanently locked to prevent X" is much more appropriate than the misleading/untrue "there is an ongoing debate" etc. There is no debate. It will remain locked, as overwhelmingly stated in this thread. So why not just say that? This detracts from the message when it is actually used while certain posts are being debated.

Comment: @Tommy simply because such option does not exist, technically.

Comment: A strange answer from a SO (programming, technical) user.

Comment: @Tommy does not technically exist in the current system written by Stack Exchange developer team. Of course they can change the code to add it, but until they do, it doesn't exist.

Comment: I imagine that changing a text field from "locked due to being debated" to "locked to prevent X" would be a trivial change. Or that message can be copied in case actual threads are debated.

Comment: @Tommy even trivial changes need testing, checking if it's not breaking other things etc. Anyway you can always submit a new feature request, since it's about the whole network maybe better do it in MSE. :)

Comment: I just find it distasteful to leave threads of high interest "locked due to debate" when there is no debate and never will be. Then, it says "see MSE" and there is no link to an actual article. This is dishonest behavior.

Comment: @Tommy I just noticed they added a Moderator's Note to the answer, did you see it? Looks like this "solve" your concern, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed! As of last night this was not the comment, but this is more upfront that it will remain locked indefinitely. Better =). But for like two years it was lying to me, LYING I TELL YOU.