# What is wrong in flagging an answer that has a wrong content format?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I just flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on Stack Overflow for wrong content format.

The content of that answer has characters like -

> onslaught of horror. Rege̿̔̉x-based HTML parsers are the cancer that
>   is killing StackOverflow it is too late it is too late we cannot be
>   saved the trangession of a chi͡ld ensures regex will consume all
>   living tissue (except for HTML which it cannot, as previously
>   prophesied) dear lord help us how can anyone survive this scourge
>   using regex to parse HTML has doomed humanity to an eternity of dread
>   torture and security holes using regex as a tool to process HTML
>   establishes a breach between this world and the dread realm of
>   c͒ͪo͛ͫrrupt entities (like SGML entities, but more corrupt) a mere
>   glimpse of the world of reg​ex parsers for HTML will ins​tantly
>   transport a programmer's consciousness into a world of ceaseless
>   screaming, he comes, the pestilent slithy regex-infection wil​l devour
>   your HT​ML parser, application and existence for all time like Visual
>   Basic only worse he comes he comes do not fi​ght he com̡e̶s, ̕h̵i​s
>   un̨ho͞ly radiańcé destro҉ying all enli̍̈́̂̈́ghtenment, HTML tags
>   lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, the song of
>   re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal
>   man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is
>   beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T
>   ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or
>   permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the
>   an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot
>   rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉
>   ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘
>   ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

I flagged this question as -

> There is some problem with the content like the one here -͟I can see
>   it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing
>   of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he
>   comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh
>   god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s
>   ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳
>   TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘
>   ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇͩ͌

But it got declined as -

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Is it wrong to flag an answer which has a content issue? Or did I flag it wrong and should have used another flag?

Comment: I can forgive you the lack of knowledge of this meme, but how can you explain the flag you have raised?

Comment: So when did you *start* to habitually waste moderator time? (and forgive me if you didn't mean this as a joke, but your flag *certainly comes across as a bad joke*).

Comment: @MartijnPieter "member for: 1 year, 11 months"

Comment: should have been declined as "doesn't require mod attention"

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you seriously explain what is wrong in that ? I really can not understand what you guys are saying

Comment: Context you may have missed: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ and http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo

Comment: @JanDvorak member for: 1 year, 11 months does not make a proof that you know everything about the world.

Comment: ..[and 91 flags and counting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250099/this-post-has-been-locked-while-disputes-about-its-content-are-being-resolved#comment637_250099). Sure wish we could disable flags on that answer.

Comment: when the questions clearly shows "viewed 1207051 times" and answer shows over 4K upvotes, I guess _everything_ is wrong about flagging it. Common sense could tell that these numbers indicate sufficient level attention given to the post already. Whatever [issues may remain there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261561/839601 "example of such an issue discussed at meta"), it is extremely unlikely that these could be fit into 500 or 600 chars limit of a flag message

Comment: Note that the Lock Text includes "The post looks exactly as it is supposed to look - there are no problems with its content. Please do not flag it for our attention."

Comment: @gnat Views, age, upvotes, etc are not a good standard by which to determine if post editing is needed. Arbitrary, individual opinion is the metric, and that's a perfectly fine reason. On smaller subs, I have 4+ yr old answers that have a steady stream of upvotes and have shown to be readable and understandable. Yet once a month, someone decides that one of them needs editing "for clarity". (if a mod ever edited my post, it was always wthin a cpl weeks) I find this one of the most annoying aspects of SE. The "permission to edit post" threshold should be MUCH higher.

Comment: @monsto my point in not that answer is totally OK (one example of the issues is even referred in [my prior comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260356/what-is-wrong-in-flagging-an-answer-that-has-a-wrong-content-format?noredirect=1#comment141563_260356)), but that there are no _simple_ problems left in there - nothing that one could explain in a simple 500-char flag message

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You apparently missed out that the post is *deliberately* using Unicode to express horror at the thought of trying to parse HTML with regex.

[Bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) used the [Zalgo meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo) to incredible effect; his post is an artwork for it.

Also see http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Your flag text comes over as if you were trying to make a joke along the same lines.

Comment: The OP was not trying to make a joke along the same lines. They were simply including an excerpt of the answer in the flag message.

Comment: Finally I understood the HTML regex thing. Everyone just laughed it off when I asked about it.

Answer (score 29):

There is Ɲ̴Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍TH̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎IN̐G wrong with that post to warrant flagging it.

Answer (score 17):

Even if this did have issues with the formatting (it doesn't, it's part of the answer), flagging it for moderator attention is ridiculous, you should just **edit it**.

That said, clearly **the moderators are already aware** of this answer, as shown by the lock on it, so obviously no action needs to be taken by you here.

Comment: It is *locked*, you **cannot** edit it. It has been locked because many people have misunderstood that the Unicode effects are *the whole point* and are trying to 'repair' it. So people keep flagging it instead, because they don't often come across locks, so they assume the thing is *really* broken then.

Comment: I'm aware you cannot edit it because it is locked, but the lock itself shows moderators are aware so no need to flag. For any other answer / question which had formatting issues, editing it should be the correct thing, not flagging it. 

I address the fact it's locked in my second paragraph.

Answer (score -10):

I'm only half serious about this, but...

This would of course require a SW change to implement this behavior... Perhaps anyone should be allowed to edit it, but only they could see their edit, sort of a "ghost edit". =)

The post would actually remain locked. That way, those who "get it" would continue to see the answer as it currently is, and those that feel it should be edited could do so and wouldn't be inclined to flag it.

Comment: So there are two things wrong with this answer:  it doesn't actually answer the question, and it's also proposing a new feature.  I'd recommend that you post this as a feature request instead, but take caution:  it is more than likely not going to be received well.

Comment: Your feature request might propose that attempted edits to and/or flagging of that Q&A should result in an automatic issued editing ban or flagging ban. The person has clearly not read the post or the lock message.