# When a post is "disputed", have the "visit meta" link actually link to the disputing post

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, locked-posts

Someone asked another question about matching XML with regular expressions today, and, as per the usual, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1435657) ended up getting linked.  For the first time, though, I saw the following line at the bottom:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved.  For more info, [visit here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

The "visit here" is a link.  But it just links to the front page of meta.stackoverflow.com.  This is pretty useless, as it doesn't actually provide any more info about why the post is in dispute.

Thus the feature request: have the "visit here" link actually link to the meta post wherein the SO post is being disputed.  Makes it much more helpful!

---

[image: visit_meta]

Comment: The problem is that post notices aren't customizable, and indeed, a content dispute notice can be applied without there actually being a meta post.

Comment: @BoltClock Hm.  I have no idea what the moderator UI is like, obviously, but maybe the team could give you guys just like a text box or something like that to paste a URL into.  Seems like that kind of feature would be useful for more than one notice.  I get what you're saying, though.

Comment: @BoltClock, how can there be a dispute without a discussion? Who is resolving if nothing is happening? Ergo, how can a content dispute notice be applied without a meta post?

Comment: @Jordy That's kind of my thinking and the assumption I was making.  I guess he's saying that the moderators might just bring up the discussion in Chat or offline somehow, without there being a Meta post at all.  But in that scenario, it seems like one could be generated and assigned to the Community user.  Or it could simply be a moderator's responsibility to create such a post in the event of a dispute.

Comment: Related: [Is there a meta post/record regarding the disputes about the content of the classic regex-for-xhtml answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129577)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I find it interesting that the "dispute" has been going on for two years.  Maybe it's time to actually clean that up?

Comment: @JeffGohlke: *Why*? People *think* the post is somehow broken, so they constantly try to edit it, or flag it for moderator attention. **That is the dispute**, it is not actually broken or needs fixing. [Most recent example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260356/what-is-wrong-in-flagging-an-answer-that-has-a-wrong-content-format).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough.  It seems like the message could be clearer, then, or still have the link point to that Stack Exchange Meta post (which would have prevented this question from being created to begin with).

Comment: @JeffGohlke: There is no way to lock a post with a custom message, the only option for that post is to lock it with a dispute message. In a way it is indeed disputed. The message just tells you that you can find more info on Meta, and that *includes asking about what the fuss is about*. There doesn't have to be a pre-existing meta post.

Comment: Related: [Can we do something about misleading message and link on locked questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141669), [Have locked question directly link to its respective meta discussion if existing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190482), ["Post Locked" should link to the meta FAQ on post locking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173624)

Comment: @Jordy: The dispute can take the form of a comment war, which might have been removed, or a rollback war, which can always be seen in the revision history.

Answer (score 5):

For this to work the locking would have to create the meta post to link to, as it probably won't exist at the time the question is locked.

Who would the question be owned by? What would it say?

Comment: I guess I'm assuming that a Meta post already exists.  How else would a moderator become informed of a potential issue to begin with?  (You're a moderator, so you might be able to actually answer that question.)  If a post didn't exist yet, though, the message could easily generate a new Meta post which is owned by the Community user with some generic message about a post being disputed.

Comment: "The [following Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved.  Please discuss the dispute in this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 "  Or something.

Comment: Or it could simply be a moderator's responsibility to create such a post in the event of a dispute.

Comment: @JeffGohlke - moderators get informed of a dispute through flags. Either raised by users or automatically raised by the system. There's very rarely a meta post create first. Also, moderators have enough to do already without having to create meta posts.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  That makes sense.