# Please stop linking to the "Zalgo" / anti-Cthulhu regex rant

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, specific-answer, zalgo

Anyone who has stopped for more than 5 seconds in the regex tag knows of this ["dubious"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134957/191410) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/211627):

> Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp.

I know that it's funny. I know this answer will never be deleted because it has [historical value](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

But, whether you love this answer or hate it, whether you think it's funny or vitriolic, the plain truth is that it doesn't represent a good answer:

- [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)
- [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/191410)

For that reason alone, I think it would be best if fellow SO users *voluntarily* **stopped linking to it via comments** in favor of more relevant, higher-quality answers.

I am **not asking that this link be banned** in any way, shape or form.

I know that users are constantly posting these questions and they get annoying. We already have approved ways of dealing with that: downvote, close (not constructive, too localized, duplicate) and delete. If your goal in linking to that answer is to indicate to the OP that the question shouldn't have been asked, then perhaps you would consider sticking to downvoting and voting to close.

There have been over [1,100 links](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116837) to this question/answer since 2008 (that's nearly [2% of all questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116935) tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) - and that includes questions before this answer was posted). There have been nearly 150 this year alone.

In the cases I've seen, the OP was relatively new or clueless about regexes. This answer does not help them - it only contains a very weak suggestion at the end that a parser should be used (without ever actually explaining **why** regexes won't work - a very ineffective argument for the determined "n00b"). In my opinion, to many new users, it could easily come off as rude, caustic or snooty. I don't think that's the reputation we want for StackOverflow.

To be clear: parsing HTML with the help of regex, [while possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627) in some regex flavors, *should be highly discouraged*. The cases where regex is an easier/cheaper tool than a true HTML parser are few and far between. That is not the issue... the issue is that *this particular answer*, at the very, very least, according to our own standards, is **not a good answer**.

To be clear: I am [not suggesting that we hold newbies' hands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180715/191410). I am merely pointing out that *this answer* is not a good answer according to the standards published in the FAQ.

**Our standards for good answers:**

- [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

> - **Answer the question**
>   Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.
>   *This question just barely squeaks by with a "Have you tried using an XML parser instead?" at the end. Beyond this, there was no attempt to explain the issues or the alternatives.*

> - **Writing style matters**
>   Nobody’s perfect — but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back and edit your answer to improve it at any time.
>   *The spelling and grammar are intentionally bad. While it works toward the comedic affect of the post, I don't think SO is meant to be a comedy house.*

> - **Always be polite and have fun**
>   It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil. There’s a real human being on the other end of that network connection, however misguided they may appear to be. We’re here to learn from our peers, not yell at each other.
>   *Please, someone, explain to me how this answer could possibly be construed as civil or polite. If I gave an answer like this to my manager, I'd probably get a reprimand.*

- [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/191410)

> - **You cannot do that in X because it doesn't support Y.**
>   *There are no links to documentation (which are requested if possible) even though plenty of documentation exists.*

> - **This is what you're doing incorrectly. [Explain]. Here's how it should be done [code].**
>   *This answer does not attempt to explain the issue or to provide the correct approach.*

> - **Try this: [code]**
>   *Again, no attempt to explain*

> - **This is the problem: [Explain]. In a related answer/blog post, I/they discuss blah [link] which might be of interest.**
>   *Again, no attempt at explanation.*

**There are plenty of good answers which already exist.** Not the least of which is [this one (Regular expression pattern not matching anywhere in string)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/211627) which has answers that actually answer the question and then explain, in exceptional detail, why this path is not ideal in most cases.

As noted in the comments/answers below, there is an especially good resource question available for PHP-specific HTML parsing questions: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Comment: +∞ while the rant itself is humorous, links to it are used in an unhelpful slapdown manner. And I delete them whenever I see them.

Comment: "This answer does not help them - it comes off as rude, caustic and snooty." It does? Maybe we have different standards on that. Despite that I agree that it is not a good answer in the sense we would like, it is far better from a simple "Don't do it". And if there is a better answer available, why not link to that? Also, are you aware that, despite this being Meta and we all are beings with unlimited power, we can not stop people from doing that except for deleting that answer? I'm 100% positive that nobody on SE will put an answer on the blacklist for comments.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - I have provided an alternative link. And as it's marked [tag:discussion], I'm not requesting that we block these links. Only that people stop linking to it of their own volition.

Comment: And you think that works? Meta is only frequented by a small percentage of users from SO. Even if all Meta-Users which read this stop doing that...then still everyone would do it! I mean, we can try to establish a Community-Rule for that...but we also have a Community-Rule for not using link shorteners, and it is actively enforced (with guns and ostrichs and stuff)...and SO is still drowning in them.

Comment: Well... At least *in theory*... You discuss something here and then you link to the discussion in comments on the main site rather than re-hashing it every single time, @M.NightDemonbobby. Not saying that'll work, but if folks are cargo-culting in comments it beats trying to argue with them.

Comment: [Listen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfl6Lu3xQW0), don't mention the Cthulhu post. I mentioned it once, but I think I got away with it. Also, isn't it _[Zalgo](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo)_, not Cthulhu?

Comment: @Cyborgx37, I wasn't being that serious.

Comment: @Servy - For that reason I carefully avoided saying it's a *bad* answer. But it's not a *good* answer either, and there are much, much better readily ones available. In fact, the one I linked to even [had the intended affect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#comment4584674_4234491)!

Comment: Is there a canonical "don't use regular expressions to parse HTML" answer? Maybe if one were created and everything was closed as a dupe then that could solve the "problem"?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Keep in mind that more text isn't always better.  I know I wouldn't link to that post most of the time because a large percentage of readers wouldn't get past the first paragraph or two, and they'd need to read much more than that to get a valuable answer.  That post has a lot of fluff that probably just shouldn't be there, and it doesn't have the most valuable information at the start, with the tangents at the end where they'll only be read by the more motivated readers.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - it's spelled out pretty clearly in the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Even so, it's difficult to come up with a canonical answer because there are cases where it is perfectly fine to parse HTML with regex (such as when the HTML is well-formed, static and the information can be easily queried). It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - For what it's worth: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/191410

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I agree that it isn't a great answer for the reasons you mentioned, and neither regex nor HTML are strong pointsd for me so I won't weigh in on the technical merits of the answer, but from discussions I've seen, it is a common [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that inexperienced programmers try to use for parsing HTML, and sometimes the humor and/or shock value of such an answer has a more lasting impact on someone than a short easy to read answer.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I would almost say that tchrist's post isn't an answer either, it's mostly self promotion and then a perl program, that uses regex true, that is actually a parser in and of itself. It, in no way, actually demonstrates that you can use a regular expression for anything beyond a very small simple subset of html. So the rant still stands that you ***CAN'T*** use just a regex to parse html, it CAN'T be done.  You can use them as part of a *parser* but it still **takes a parser!** to consume html beyond any type of small subset.

Comment: @ryan you might want to read the comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245008/php-regex-simple-regex-for-bbcode-s-or-strike-fails-to-work. tchrist makes a lot of good points there. I stopped linking to the rant afterwards because I realized the rant is not giving an accurate picture. The reasons not to use Regex on HTML is not that HTML is not regular.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I would argue (and have argued in comments before) that it is far more effective to overwhelm someone by showing them just how difficult the task they are taking on is (and how easy the alternative is) then it is to throw clearly sarcastic drivel at them. That's why I like the linked answer - seeing the enormity of creating their own parser makes them reconsider the task ahead. [And it works, too!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#comment4584674_4234491)

Comment: @Gordon I didn't say that you couldn't do it because HTML isn't regular, I also would argue with tchrist that what he is using and calling 'modern regular expressions' don't even qualify as regular expressions and should be named something like `perl expressions`. tchrist is smart, and he is a leading authority on perl but he is also pompous in the extreme. I'm sorry but I have to disagree with tchrist and you. In **none** of the links here or in your discussion with him, did he show me any evidence that a regex ***by its self*** can parse html.

Comment: @ryan I didn't link it to convince you of it. I linked it because tchrist himself says it doesn't matter. Quoting: *Now I agree; it doesn’t matter whether regexes can do something given the availability of alternatives that are shorter, easier, and more robust.* - and that's the whole problem with the rant. It gives the wrong reasons for not parsing Regex with HTML.

Comment: @ryan - I'd like to see a situation where someone is trying to parse *and use* HTML with nothing more than regex. I'd be willing to bet that in 100% of cases where someone is trying to parse HTML with regex, they are doing so via a third language (perl, .NET, javascript). In that sense, tchrist is correct. And, in any case, this discussion is quickly diverging from the point of the post.

Comment: That answer is not ideal, but sometimes the illness is worse than the medicine. Here is that case. Thank you for linking to that epic answer!

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks. I hadn't considered the other possible interpretations of that title. I was wondering where all of the "don't ban the links" stuff was coming from.

Comment: Related: [Why does the RegEx answer keep getting locked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134933)

Comment: Why does this question comes up over and over again?  And why does it need to be answered over and over again?  Just vote to close the question as duplicate.  And link to *your* favorite answer instead.

Comment: @UphillLuge - See *"I know that users are constantly posting these questions and they get annoying. We already have approved ways of dealing with that: downvote, close (not constructive, too localized, duplicate) and delete."*

Comment: If I could downvote this more than once, I'd spend at least ten minutes doing nothing but clicking on the downvote arrow over and over and over again.

Comment: @JackManey - I believe that Gordon♦'s +∞ would annihilate ten minutes worth of non-stop downvoting. ;)

Comment: Well, +|P(R)|, then (where P(R) denotes the power set of the set of real numbers). :P

Comment: @JackManey - By which of the official Stack Overflow policies on answering questions would you argue that the Zalgo answer is a good one? Were a post like this created today, it would almost certainly be deleted within hours (if not minutes). It's funny and part of SO history, but would you actually go so far as to argue that it does a good job explaining regexes? In fact, it is actually incorrect in stating that HTML cannot be parsed by regexes (which has been proved over and over)... it should say that parsers are significantly easier and cheaper to use.

Comment: @Gordon As a non-helpful joke-answer, I believe the Zalgo answer should be deleted. Furthermore, linking to it is obnoxious and rude. [Infinitely better to link to an answer that actually provides a working answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272) than to just flip somebody off with a joke. ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: This is completely valid and needs to be moved to meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: @Gordon If you really are going around and mass deleting links that people post, I believe you have overstepped as a moderator.  By all means delete away when the links aren't relevant and don't add to the discussion, but they often do and if you are blindly deleting because you disagree with the answer then I don't believe you should be moderating.

Comment: @Brad gross overgeneralisation is gross.

Comment: @Gordon I'm glad we're in agreement.  (And, please note the `if` statements in my comment.)

Comment: `-math.exp(10, 1000000)` Out of nothing but pure spite, I found an appropriate question on SO and posted a link to that answer in the comment section.

Comment: @JDB, «it is actually incorrect in stating that HTML cannot be parsed by regexes». It is **correct.** Regular expressions are for regular (Level 3) languages, while HTML is a context-free (Level 2) language. If some programming languages implement tools which are incorrectly called regexes but are actually pseudo-working parser, or if the OP is incorrectly using the verb "parsing" is another story.

Comment: Definitions are not pedantic. There are correct definitions and wrong definitions. The "regular" in "regular expressions" refers to regular languages. Besides, also extended regular expressions with back-tracking may not be suitable to write a parser. «I doubt people who are asking this question have level 3 vs 2 languages in mind» Precisely, here's why it's a good idea to explain to them that **parsing** a context-free grammar cannot be done using a regular language.

Comment: «in contrast to the rest of programmer-dom» [citation needed] «I still contend that the article in question does a very poor job» I never mentioned the article in question. I only corrected your wrong claim that it is possible to parse HTML with regex. Sure you can lex it, but then you're changing the premises. You were talking about parsing. Nevertheless, the **first 6 sentences** of the funny/dubious answer explain exactly the problem and what can't be done. The pun is left at the end.

Comment: Mentioning Larry Wall is a pretty nice *Argumentum ab auctoritate.* The problem is, the mere presence of back-references in popular *extended* regex engines does not provide a parser. You might want to check out [The true power of regular expressions](https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html): «Only problem is: Even though regular expressions can *match* context-free languages nicely, they can’t usually *parse* them. Parsing means converting some string into an abstract syntax tree.»

Comment: «or at least lexing» Lexing can be achieved with "normal" regex, no need to use Perl extensions. Lexers *are* implemented with regex. I'm not appealing to Chomsky, I'm using the correct mathematical / computational definition. Still, extended regex can *match* context-free languages but they **cannot** parse them. Show me a piece of code that builds an AST with only regex and no external high-level logic (loops, stacks and so on).

Comment: Congratulations, you two, you have expressed in 10 comments what the very answer you're discussing did in 10 sentences.

Comment: @JDB: By making such a trivial edit, you've bumped this age-old question up the "active" page. Was that really necessary?

Comment: @Cerbrus - Normally, I'd say it wasn't, but I've been getting some heat about whether or not Regexes can technically parse HTML. I changed my language to clarify. It probably won't stay on top for long.

Comment: I seem to recall that Back In The Day (tm) the first two rules of Usenet were: 1: Do not be overly annoying, and 2: Do not be overly annoyed. Words to live by...

Comment: This rant was funny the first time I saw it. Now it is just annoying. Mostly because it is the first response to questions that happen to have HTML. (If the OP just wanted to match any word coming after "Hello", any HTML based argument is immediately invalid, and thus annoying)

Comment: Perhaps this has already been suggested (I haven't scanned this entire thread) but maybe there should be a helpful link up top that says something like "This answer is a joke, and is kept around for historical reasons: for a real answer, see <some link here>" ...  or whatever bland phrasing SO requires of such texts now.  People tend to link to the answer itself, so yes it would require editing that answer, not just the top header of the ... page? post? thread?  Not sure of SO's nomenclature here.

Comment: `I know that users are constantly posting these questions and they get annoying` Yet you offer the alternative of downvoting and closing to cure the annoyance. Isn't the _CURE_ to just ignore the question and move on ? Wouldn't that be the _NEUTRAL_ solution to espouse to ? Instead, you just _PILE ON_ with a real penalty. I happen to believe every html and xml tags can be parsed with regular expressions. The form of _tags_ is in fact defined using regular expressions. This has nothing to do with regex and html.

Comment: @Maxt8r Please note that this suggestion is 7 years old. The conversation around it has been exhaustively covered. All I'll say is that if you believe that any post is of poor quality, then it is better to use sanctioned mechanisms to clear the site of the low quality post. Rude and snide comments are not the proper solution. In the years since this suggestion was posted, new flags have been introduced for rude comments, so it's not as much of a concern anymore. If you believe the specific question you are looking at is fine, then this post is irrelevant to you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I spend some time going through the list of answers in that question, and find that most of the answers **don't offer a way out**. In my opinion, **a good explanation on why regex should not be used to parse HTML, with some library recommendation at the end** makes a good reference to link to whenever someone tries to parse HTML with regex.

Here are my opinion on some of the top voted answers:

- The Cthulhu answer explains somewhat about why Perl (which has recursive regex) cannot parse HTML, but a bit lacking in details. The second half of the answer doesn't contain any useful information. The key point for this answer is mostly the last sentence that recommend the use of HTML parser instead of using regular expression. However, there is no information on the recommended tools or libraries to manipulate HTML.
- The [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1400768) is acceptable, in the sense that it tells the limit on the use case of regex on parsing HTML. But no information on how to do it properly.
- The [3rd most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/1400768) uses the reasoning with theoretical regular expression, but regular expression in programming languages are usually more powerful than theoretical regular expression. The argument is a bit crooked at this point.
- The [4th most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1736801/1400768) attempts to answer the question with regex. No comment.
- The [5th most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236278/1400768) is not an answer, IMO. I think it should be deleted.
- The [6th most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233151/1400768) contains a chunk of **deflated** and base-64 encoded text, which is quite annoying to get the content out of. I think the author does this so no one can use copy and paste the solution, but it also hides away the regex so that no one can check it.
- [Next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732595/1400768) suggests a library for PHP.
- [Next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263520/1400768) is most likely not an answer, since it suggests Turing.sed, which is an emulator for a Turing machine.
- [Next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737662/1400768) is **an example** in PHP with `DOMDocument`.
- [Next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564061/1400768) is an example in .NET with regex and open/closing group with some assumption on input HTML. No comment on accuracy.
- [Next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732395/1400768) is another regex solution, with no clear assumption.
- [Next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745488/1400768) is a library recommendation for .NET (no example).
- [An answer a bit below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1744154/1400768) is a comparison between the libraries in PHP.
- Beyond are a bunch of regex answers and library recommendation (without example). And the graveyard of deleted answers including some link-only library recommendation and spams.

In my opinion, a ***resource question*** with a **regularly maintained** list of library for HTML parsing (like the list of books in C++ tag) is much more useful. Or even a ***resource question*** with a list of links to SO questions with examples of parsing HTML in particular language is also useful.

Currently, as Gordon has commented, the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) has a reference question for parsing HTML: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml). This serves as an excellent example of resource question as I mentioned above, and is something that is more useful for the asker.

Comment: I like the idea of a resource question, but are you aware of one that exists? Could such a question even exist on the site without being closed?

Comment: @Cyborgx37: I think resource questions are acceptable. However, 1) it must be some sort of resource that is going to be commonly used (which is the case here) 2) it should be regularly maintained.

Comment: We have that for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml and it includes a section about Regex with reasonable explanation why you likely don't want to use them.

Comment: @Gordon: That is something what I hope people would link to (for PHP tag), and something that I would like to see for other tags. The Cthulhu answer is funny, but it doesn't tell when regex should/should not be used and what are the libraries suitable for the task.

Comment: @nhahtdh actually, that's why I wrote it ;)

Comment: "there is no information on the recommended tools or libraries to manipulate HTML" - because [tool recommendations are forbidden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222790/request-to-reopen-so-question-on-javascript-error-detection#comment725161_222790) perhaps?

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Tool recommendation questions are closed right away. However, if the question asks "how to parse", it is fine for the answer to be a library recommendation.

Comment: "However, there is no information on the recommended tools or libraries to manipulate HTML."

Because recommended tools is against the rules... The rules are against the rules. Another reason I rarely come here anymore and ask my questions to respectable communities in open discussion format.

Comment: @LeeLouviere: Read the comment right above yours. And we don't like a page full of links to tools. They are useless. Rather, something like what the link Gordon posted is what I'm thinking about.

Comment: @nhahtdh I can promise you I've seen questions / answers closed looking for or recommending libraries. Tool/library are quite synonymous for the same reasons. The information becomes outdated.
Now if the question is how a certain tool or library method behaves because it is not behaving as expected, that's not outdated because the question is tied to a certain point in the lifespan/context of that tool or library. But recommendations are never tied to lifespan or context.

Comment: @LeeLouviere: **I'm not sure what you want to add to this discussion.** Sure, tool/library questions are not welcomed, since they attracts low quality answers and becomes outdated fast. However, exceptions are given to questions which are frequently maintained by the community. Example can be seen in C++ books question (currently wiki-lock, only allow edit on answers), and the above question. If you have a better solution to teach people how to parse HTML properly, feel free to suggest in an answer. This is the best solution I can come up with.

Comment: «why regex should not be used to parse HTML» Again, we're not talking about the fact that you *should not* parse HTML with regex, the fact is that you *cannot* parse a context-free language with tools for dealing with regular languages. You can't write a parser with regex, you can use them to write a lexer, which is a different tool. The "a bit crooked" argument is actually correct. Regex are very clearly defined. If programming languages use the wrong term, that's another story. If you buy a "router" which has an integrated firewall, you are not buying a router (Network level appliance).

Comment: The author of the deflated regex did so because it's too large to fit an answer otherwise. Since this is the smallest regex that can actually *do* it and it doesn't fit without shenanigans, it's not that bad a choice. OP can actually use it because he was helpful enough to provide the surrounding code.

Answer (score 94):

First off, comments are not answers. You should not judge them the same way you would an answer. I see absolutely nothing wrong leaving a link to that post on related questions *in the comments*. It's related, relevant, and imo worth the read.

Second, I find that post actually does have value to a newbie because it makes it clear, in no uncertain terms, that regex parsers are not a good idea. You can find out why by reading dry boring posts about the gory details, but that post is an entertaining way to make it clear in a way that words can't describe, that regex parsers are *bad* and will make you go insane.

And last of all, the other answers in that post are quite useful for anyone interested in writing an HTML parser using regex.

So no, don't stop linking to it if you come across a situation where it would apply :)

(Also, I think that answer is a true work of art that shows off the creativity and humor of the SE community, which I would think is something we'd want to broadcast, not suppress and/or delete)

Comment: There are other better answers out there to link to, IMO.

Comment: @nhahtdh Then link to those answers.  Nobody's saying that you *must* link to this answer, only that it shouldn't be prohibited/discouraged.

Comment: @Servy: People usually don't link to those answers. That's the problem here. Either we improve the current Cthulhu answer, or make a resource question.

Comment: Rachel, what's the point of linking to an answer in the comments? If the answer isn't good, why would we want people to link to it? This answer isn't good by our own standards, so why would we not discourage people from linking to it? I'm not proposing a ban, but I think linking to it is less than helpful in nearly all situations.

Comment: @Servy - can we update the Zalgo answer to include links to more appropriate answers listing tools and technologies available to users? Maybe a discussion of when and how to use regex vs a parser? The would at least make all of the existing links just a tad more helpful.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 and nhahtdh, I cannot take any suggestion that the Zalgo answer be modified with any seriousness. Just link to something else if you do not like it. It's not that hard.

Comment: @user414076: Well, I hope people would come to meta and understand why the post is fun, but not that helpful to link to. The thing is that people usually only links to the Zalgo answer only, which makes it the only thing the asker read.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I frequently leave links to other answers when I think the OP would appreciate reading them and benefit from the content based on their question, when the linked answer doesn't completely answer the OP's question, or when I don't have time to write up a full answer myself, but still want to point them in the right direction. In the case of this post, I would link to it if I think the OP or others with the same question would appreciate reading the answer, and could benefit from it in some way related to their question.

Comment: @nhahtdh, it is exceptionally helpful and accomplishing its purpose. Further, that question has more than 730,000 views. Obviously, someone finds it useful. Leave it alone. It is beyond Stack Overflow now, it belongs to the internet.

Comment: @user414076: I don't suggest to delete it (and I never do), but I agree with Cyborgx37 to stop linking to it, or link to it (to convince the OP not to use regex), plus some other helpful way out (library).

Comment: @Rachel - You exercise more care than most of the cases where I've seen this used. Look at the list of comments in this SEDE query and consider how many are actually useful: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116837. In many cases I've seen, these were "drive-by" comments where the commentor made no attempt to understand what was being asked. In some cases, regex was actually an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I can't speak for everyone, but I think banning the use of a specific link that isn't actively harmful, and is possibly even helpful in many cases, is a bad idea :)

Comment: @Rachel - I don't know why people think I've suggested banning it. I've stated [over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant/182210?noredirect=1#comment554723_182189) and [over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant/182210?noredirect=1#comment554808_182208) again that I'm not trying to have it banned. I'm just asking people not to use it in favor of higher quality answers.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Sorry, I do realize that and tried to avoid suggesting that in my answer :)

Comment: "creativity and humor of the SE community, which I would think is something we'd want to broadcast" - that might have been the case back [in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/1269037) [the](http://is.gd/xLJ2Hn) [golden](http://is.gd/JltdfS) [days](http://is.gd/7v6voK), but now [it](http://is.gd/YG6zi0) [surely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50106/150034) [is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12498308/1269037) *[no longer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223009/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results/223101?noredirect=1#comment728748_223101)*.

Comment: @ZDB You are exactly right.  People are using it inappropriately, even in places where pattern matching is indeed the right answer.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thank you for that archive link, I remembered seeing it before but had not saved it.  Quality of its contents is pretty random, bit it is filled with massively useful information that is extremely disappointing to have been deleted...

Answer (score 11):

> "**There are plenty of good answers which already exist.** Not the least of which is [this one (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/211627)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/211627) which has answers that actually answer the question and then explain, in exceptional detail, why this path is not ideal in most cases."

I'd just like to say that that's actually **a pretty awful question** to link to — out of the six current answers, only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234582) is actually valid and useful, and it's pretty far down the page:

- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231482) is simply wrong.  It tries to solve a very small subset of the general HTML parsing problem, *and it still fails to do it.*  See the comments to that answer for some examples of valid inputs that will break it.
- Below that, [tchrist's enormous and hugely upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491) is extremely impressive — but hardly more useful than the Zalgo rant to someone who just *actually wants to parse some HTML.*  Indeed, Tom admits that himself in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/4584407):

  > "That was kinda my point, actually. I wanted to show how hard it is. –  tchrist Nov 20 '10 at 19:38"
- The [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234582) by meder is, IMO, the only valid and useful one.  It doesn't actually contain a single regexp, but rather explains how to properly parse and extract data from HTML using DOMDocument and DOMXpath in PHP.  Of course, it would be even better to link to [the reference question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).
- [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638578) basically just consists of a link to [the *REX* paper by Robert D. Cameron](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Ecameron/REX.html).  It's actually a pretty nice paper, and it *does* contain code for a usable and reasonably compact regexp-based XML parser in the appendices.  Alas, REX is an XML parser, not an HTML parser, and it cannot cope with various features (like unquoted attribute values) that are legal in HTML but not in XML.
- The [remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882632) two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734264) are broken in similar ways as the accepted one.  There's really nothing to recommend in either of them.

Comment: If you prefer a different answer, that's up to you. It doesn't change the purpose of the post, though. (Personally, if an OP seems dead-set on using rexeges, I like the tchrist post because it demonstrates just what is involved in building a full-on parser.)

Comment: All the linking to the locked post is doing more harm than good, and should be banned: ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Answer (score 3):

Some of the historical context is missing for that question. There are certain restricted subsets of HTML and use cases where regex will do. This always made it difficult to work out when you needed what. You can also parse HTML with algorithms involving multiple chunks of regex. While you're using regex, you're also filling in using the logic and semantics of your programming languages such as loops, recursion, stacks, variables, etc.

A prevailing problem is that for a long time as standard you didn't get parsers that were the same as those in the browser. Although many people would say to just use this or that it would be hard to ensure results would match that of browsers. A very common case would be when the attempt was made to switch everything over to full strict XML with the common suggestion to then use an XML parser.

Things have improved a lot but in the historical context you could get this question then suggest around half a dozen parsers for a given language but find it very difficult to be sure that any of those fully parallel the parsing the browser does in all cases.

Such libraries haven't always had such obvious interfaces either that make it as simple as it would seem with regex to take a string and for example extract a list of specific tags. Although this is also an improving front it's something that's often over looked.

One of the underlying causes for this situation to arise is that there have been always easy answers but its never been historically easy to give good thorough answers because there's rarely been a stable definition of HTML.

For the longest time the only true HTML parsing software has been browsers and they typically have been applications rather than libraries. Many people also forget that HTML is SGML based, not XML based.

For the simpler use cases it can be easier to prescribe something specifically that works and in some cases that can even be regular expression. It should be respected that for generic solutions it has always been hard to give a generic answer that'll work in general. That's part of why you have don't use regex but people struggle to propose what to use instead (for more reasons than there being endless XML/HTML libs but regex being fairly standard, true HTML parsers have often been few and far between).

This isn't a problem when you're on a webpage and you open the developer tools then use the inbuilt representation of the parsed page. This all happens on the backend when those libraries aren't available. In the real world, people write HTML for the frontend or for that application and not for backend applications such as python, etc. The only good generic solution is a full port of DOM from whatever the most common browser is.

For your own HTML specifically rather than others, you can rely on something simpler if you intend to be consistent and not have errors in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it would be best if fellow SO users **stopped linking to it via comments**.

If I understand correctly, your reasoning is similar to one that justified LMGTFY and WHYT bans:

- [Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/165773)
- ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/165773)

Both bans were intended to stop massive misuse of references to particular (otherwise helpful) resources.

If you want something like that, consider providing data to verify that *amount* of misuse is sufficient to justify ban. As an example, [WHYT ban request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/165773) was supported by SEDE queries demonstrating the usage of problematic references.

---

Note, as opposed to fully general LMGTFY and WHYT references, the one you are talking about might turn out specific to particular tag(s) ([html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)?), you might want to take this into account.

In particular, I think it would be reasonable to expect *tag-specific* ban request to be supported by data showing that

1. problematic references represent a *substantial* fraction of comments in target tag(s)
2. affected tag(s) in turn, represent a *substantial* (popular, active) fraction of Stack Overflow questions

Comment: The question is in the spirit of [*"Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). This is not a feature request, and I did support my claims with a SEDE query. (See the link on `1,100 links`)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 as far as I understand, LMGTFY and WHYT references in comments were banned for similar reasons (not being helpful for new users). As for 1,100 links, the way you present these, it appears spread over 5,000,000 SO questions, making one feel that the problem is very _very_ minor - I'd say one needs some more focused analysis to make it look worth considering

Comment: LMGTFY and "What have you tried" were often seen as comments by drive-by users who didn't really have an interest in helping out the user, and who only wanted to point out that the user was stupid by missing the obvious. They created an unfriendly atmosphere on SO, which I believe is why they got banned. Links the regex rant are not  really the same.

Comment: @Gnat - Again, though, I'm not asking for a ban. Regex is not the most active tag and any automated solution probably isn't worth the time, which is why this is not a feature request. It's just a discussion. I'm getting tired of hashing this out in question comments.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: I think you can try updating the question with the ID of the question also, since there are people who link to the question instead of the answer.

Comment: Probably worth noting that WHYT links aren't banned entirely; just the sort of content-free comments *with* WHYT links that were proliferating irresponsibly.

Comment: @gnat Even though it might feel like it sometimes, there aren't 5,000,000 regex questions.  Looks like a more modest ~60,000 that at least have the regex tag.  It's unlikely for someone to post the regex answer on a non-regex question, so 1100/60000 is a better comparison.

Comment: @gnat - My revised query shows [1.955%](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116935).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I would add that regex questions look quite popular: [over 7,500 have more than 1K views](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+views%3A1000), and about 4,000 of these have over 2K views, these sum up to about 10,000,000 views total. 2% of this make 500,000 views - that would estimate audience of the comments you ask about. Not as accurate as it could be with SEDE though - if "Ctulhu" references tend to be in lower viewed questions, things could look less impressive

Comment: Yes, linking to it is both unhelpful and rude. ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: Never say never. LMGTFY can be used to show what range of options there are, even that there are none, too many, hard to find or none that are good. Even for valid use cases it has a problem that search results can change dramatically one day to the next.