# Bad characters in the first response

Tags: bug, design

I have found this question:

[Corrupted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

The first answer seems to be corrupted.

I see the answer as follow:

[image]

Is it an issue of my PC or not?

Comment: It's a long answer, but did you read the whole thing?  Also, that reminds me, I need to make a t-shirt of that.

Comment: Highly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260356/what-is-wrong-in-flagging-an-answer-that-has-a-wrong-content-format/260358#260358 Also: Did you even _read_ the moderator's note at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: That answer is exactly per spec. See *Invoking Zalgo through Regular Expressions* by Kamensky and Dahl.

Comment: To quote the **Moderator's Note** just visible at the bottom of your screenshot: *"The post looks exactly as it is supposed to look - there are no problems with its content."*

Comment: In fact this shows your browser is fully Unicode compliant, so it's a Good Thing. If you see just plain text you are missing out on a famous post. Since it appears to be rendered correctly, you are just missing the entire point.

Comment: You have seen. Now H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝.

Comment: Fun fact: we're now up to 99 declined flags on that answer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I [already have one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a/261514#261514).

Comment: There's a 99 luftballoons joke here somewhere, Brad, we must find it.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: You've missed the boat on that one, I'm afraid: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108395/

Comment: @BradLarson Maybe it's time to consider a historical lock on the whole question. It solves 2 problems: 1) The flagging. 2) The other answers "catching up" in votes. The only downside is that the historical lock message may be inappropriate and misleading since the question itself is valid and on-topic. I don't know if the lock message can be customized.

Answer (score 23):

The answer is exactly what ͠it's s҉u҉̸p̸͝p͡o̶͞se̴͝d t̴̩͚̰̼͝o̻̝͔̼̬̻͕͍̭  b̵̧̤̥̩̩̣̬̦̲̯̖̒͊̽̒̏͟͡ͅe̡̯̰̟̗͚̜̗͕̤̲͎̠ͮͯ̓̈̄.