# This answer should be deleted, 2 flags have been declined

Tags: support, declined-flags

I've flagged [this self-answer with a score of -15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5662412/1317805) twice. All it says is:

> Resolved... I used a div with that properties and inserted it in the table cell.

*That properties* here refers to the `overflow: scroll` property given in [DavW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5662431/1317805) on the question. This answer is essentially: *I modified my code to reflect what was given in DavW's answer and it worked!* ...which is quite obviously a comment and not an answer.

The first time I flagged it as *very low quality* and the second time as *not an answer*. Both of the flags were declined.

I'm pretty sure both flag declines are due to human error, so can it please be deleted?

Comment: It _is_ an answer, though. But I agree that it's very low quality.

Comment: Delete votes were effective: _"deleted by πάντα ῥεῖ, James Donnelly, Cerbrus just now"_

Comment: The OP has a good point - their answer came first, a whole 2 minutes earlier. You can't comment on an answer that's not there. For all we know they solved their own problem independently of the other answer - if anything I'd give the guy credit for that alone. Besides, have we forgotten that OPs have no obligation to mark an objectively "better" answer as accepted? Fine if people want to downvote it for not providing example code (probably the same kind of people who flag answers as link-only even if they paraphrased content from the link), but I'm appalled the community saw fit to delete it.

Comment: @BoltClock I kinda assumed OP edited their answer during the grace period. 1. OP posts answer, 2. other person posts answer which works for OP, 3. OP edits answer saying that it worked for them. At least, that's what it looks like to me. OPs answer doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: It's hard to tell then. I read "that properties" [sic] here as referring to the set of CSS properties given in the question.

Comment: @BoltClock the user commented on their answer: "but mine was faster **and the same**". This implies that they used the same solution DavW posted (which doesn't feature in their question). I kinda get the feeling it falls into this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172640/dealing-with-quickly-edited-copied-answers.

Comment: @James - seems like you should give OP benefit of the doubt. The OP's full quote is: [*"I up-ed his because was correct, but mine was faster and the same. Why should I accept an answer that might be a copy of mine?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662357/how-to-create-a-table-cell-that-scrolls-when-overflowing/5662412#comment24894304_5662412). This to me implies that OP came up with the answer on his own.

Comment: @chuex I fail to see how OP can say "I used a div with that properties" *before* the other answer was submitted. Even in that case "Resolved... I used a div with that properties and inserted it in the table cell." is both *Very Low Quality* and *Not an Answer*.

Comment: I think it is an answer, although a poor one.  I don't think it should be deleted - We'll have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: So... wait a second. You raised a flag, it got declined, and then you raised a second non-custom flag of a different type? Didn't it occur to you that maybe *some explanation of why you're flagging* was warranted if your flag was declined the first time? Clearly a custom flag should have been used if you insisted on a second flag.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As BoltClock points out, the answer was posted before any other answers; it is a low-quality answer, but an answer to their own question nonetheless. It cannot be a comment to the other answer because it was posted *before* that answer was ever added.

Moderators have a tiny window on each post that is flagged. Even when we look at the answer on the question page, we cannot always see that the post was flagged as NAA because you think it is merely responding to another answer.

This post has been flagged as NAA *4 times*, for example, and all 4 times those flags were rejected, because the post *reads like an answer to the question*. There is also no comment on the post explaining that it is thought to be a response to another answer.

If this really *was* merely a comment (check the dates!), please use a *custom moderator attention flag* and explain to us that a) the post is merely a response to another answer, b) it is marked accepted so it is harder for the community to deal with it and c) a moderator should delete it.

Thanks to the attention you brought to it here on Meta, the community has now deleted it. It perhaps did not deserve to be deleted, but given the quality of the post and that it is likely to only attract more downvotes, I'm leaving it be.

Comment: Thanks, will do that in future! Does beg the question though: if something has been flagged multiple times for the same reason, shouldn't it be put into some sort of investigation queue?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: no, because sometimes the community [just gets it wrong a lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260356/what-is-wrong-in-flagging-an-answer-that-has-a-wrong-content-format/260358#comment41694_260356), were *a lot* currently stands at 137 for that specific example. And it really doesn't happen all that often. There will always be exceptions, which is why we have the free-form moderation attention flag in the first place.

Comment: Ha, okay, fair point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters People are still flagging that post even with the note on it?

Comment: @TZHX: What note? ;)

Comment: @TZHX: People don't read. Not even blocks offset with a different background color and **Moderator's Note** in boldface on them. Sad but true.

Comment: I still don't understand why "we" (the community) deleted the guy's answer? He made it first, and it was correct, no? Do we now delete any downvoted answers we no longer like?

Comment: I am with @RichardLeMesurier.  Is there a point where the post is so far negative that we should delete it or should it stand and the negative votes shows how we fell about answers of that quality.  If anything it can be used as an example of what not to make your answer look like.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: it was deleted because people missed that it was posted first. I didn't check properly either, Boltclock pointed it out. I'm just letting it be because it was only going to attract more downvotes as more people would misunderstand over time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's still *Very Low Quality* and *Not an Answer* regardless of who posted the answer first. Plus, see my replies to comments on the question - I'm under the impression OP edited their answer during the grace period to reflect DavW's answer. "I used a div with that properties" - what are "that properties" if they're not referencing DavW's later-posted answer?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: no, it is **not** NAA worthy. And Very Low Quality is for posts that need deleting *now*. Voting is the correct action here; it *is* an answer to the question stated, just one worthy of downvotes as it is not helpful. The *that porperties* can equally apply to the CSS attributes mentioned in the question.

Comment: makes sense, @martijn

Comment: At this point the only reason I can think of that the community deleted it is because they have the privilege to vote to delete any downvoted answer they wish, and if they deem that an answer must go, then it goes. I can't see why I would have done that, but I'm not any of the three delete voters.

Comment: @BoltClock We can vote to delete downvoted answers? I do not recall ever seeing that button - is this a 10K+ function?

Comment: @Richard Le Mesurier: 20k+ to be precise.

Comment: @BoltClock: in the meantime, the community also *undeleted* the post, after which the OP re-deleted the answer themselves.

Comment: Guilt tripping at its finest.

Comment: I actually deleted my own post. It was an answer, a correct one (although poorly written is true). I posted the question, found the solution and wanted to delete it. But at that point I had a vote in it or something so I decided to maybe help some1. I answered BEFORE the other answer and anyone that reads both the question and the answer can understand what "that properties" mean (are in the question). The only reason I deleted it is that was gathering down votes for no reasons except lack of reading while the (better written) COPY of mine (that is also one line) was gathering upvotes.