# Why does the link with "...locked while disputes ...." message not point to a specific post?

Tags: support, locked-posts

Before anything else, I have already checked [the other question with the same title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250099/this-post-has-been-locked-while-disputes-about-its-content-are-being-resolved). It doesn't really help.

I came across one in the question *[What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum/7342171#7342171)*

[image: Locked post]
<sub>(source: [tinytake.com](https://zenoo.tinytake.com/media/7faf0f?filename=1532504982427_25-07-2018-09-49-41.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=698&height=246))</sub>

I feel like the message is either misleading or is missing some information.

It's telling me to visit meta, and I was expecting the link to send me to the meta question discussing the subject.

If it is being discussed on meta, link me to it directly! And if it's not, why link to meta at all?

Then, since the last edit was done in 2016, I feel like the disputes are taking pretty long to be resolved.

---

**TLDR;** Could we either link to the meta discussion or change the locked message?

Comment: If you see the [edit revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7342171/revisions), It looks like an old rollback war. Mods generally block the post to stop the behavior

Comment: From the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7342171/timeline) it seems that there has been a rollback-war on this answer. Most probably a mod locked it to prevent further editing. I don't think there is a meta-discussion about the answer.

Comment: Well then I feel like the locked message really is misleading.

Comment: The disputes about its content are being resolved though, the discussions are just top secret and will take 6-8 weeks

Comment: Matt was picked as a moderator in June 2015, giving him the Lock moderator right.  He is not anymore.  Too many back-and-forth rollbacks on that post, locking it is a good way to stop that.

Comment: If you have a reason to unlock an old post, just flag it and a moderator will consider it.

Comment: @BDL It tells a story of a user who really didn't want anyone to add an explanation to an answer they made a community wiki... a modern Leonidas.

Comment: @halfer I don't want the post to be unlocked, I want the locked message to reflect the actual state of the post. Not the state it was in 2 years ago.

Comment: Apparently resolution in this case will be the sun going supernova. It'll be unlocked then.

Comment: The error message is just poorly worded. What it means is "if you want to know, go *ask* meta", but read literally, it is definitely a reasonable expectation for the link to meta in the message to take you to an existing meta discussion. I would recommend you adjust this into a [meta-tag:feature-request] requesting that the error message be clarified/rewritten. As it stands, this *is* just a duplicate of the other meta Q by the same name.

Comment: [MSE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172783/more-info-on-for-more-info-visit-meta-required)

Answer (score 8):

The lock notice exists for the author(s) even more than it does for the readers. **It gives them an avenue to ask what in the heck is going on.** Situations like this are often indicative that one or more participants are confused or unaware of site policy or community norms, so directing them to Meta prompts them to seek clarification rather than continue to engage in whatever they're doing that resulted in a moderator getting involved.

The events on the post at hand are fairly clear from the history:

1. User posts link only answer.
2. Someone tries to add information to make it not link only.
3. Answerer decides they want their answer to remain link only. They're likely unaware of site policy to the contrary.
4. Multiple users proceed to engage in edit war trying to expand the answer. They may be unaware that edit wars are frowned upon.
5. The edit war resulted in a flag, possibly an automatic one or perhaps someone decided to raise it personally.
6. Moderator puts post in a middle ground state by making the post a single sentence. Moderator then locks the post to end the edit war.

Someone involved in the edit war was confused. The answerer probably wasn't aware of site policy regarding link only answers. The users continually trying to edit details in may not have been familiar with our discouragement against engaging in edit wars. If anyone had wanted to get clarification about who was following site policy/guidelines and who wasn't or how the situation could have been handled better, Meta would be the place for them to ask.

No Meta discussion had been raised on this particular post. The users trying to edit the answer into shape didn't have any questions about what content is appropriate on SO, and the answerer chose not to engage with the community to try to figure out why people were editing their post.

When a Meta discussion is actually raised, a comment linking to it is completely sufficient.

All that said, let this example drop. The question is clearly off topic and was correctly closed long ago. It doesn't matter whether the answer is locked since recommendation questions are typically poorly maintained anyway (which is why they're forbidden).

Comment: I agree that this message is useful at the time it's posted. But now, 2 years later, it's just more confusing than anything else.

Comment: "Someone tries to add information to make it not link only." is disingenuous. The edit added some text, but also added a link to a competing library. Had it been my answer, I would have rolled that right back without a second thought too.